# cython numpy accumulate function

Tags: python, performance, numpy, cython

I need to implement a function for summing the elements of an array with a variable section length.
So,

```
a = np.arange(10)
section_lengths = np.array([3, 2, 4])
out = accumulate(a, section_lengths)
print out
array([  3.,   7.,  35.])
```

I attempted an implementation in `cython` here:

https://gist.github.com/2784725

for performance I am comparing to the pure `numpy` solution for the case where the section_lengths are all the same:

```
LEN = 10000
b = np.ones(LEN, dtype=np.int) * 2000
a = np.arange(np.sum(b), dtype=np.double)
out = np.zeros(LEN, dtype=np.double)

%timeit np.sum(a.reshape(-1,2000), axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 25.1 ms per loop

%timeit accumulate.accumulate(a, b, out)
10 loops, best of 3: 64.6 ms per loop
```

would you have any suggestion for improving performance?

Comment: I implemented several suggestions, see updated version on github: https://gist.github.com/2784725/8e2aaebbaa68c67e7a0686e9c7927f2f5b6f419a, still it takes 63ms, so no significant improvement

Comment: It might be off the point, but thought I would mention... numpy already has something close to it for *all* ufuncs. `np.add.reduceat(a, section_lengths.cumsum())`. It has to be changed a bit (cumsum lacks a 0 at the start and you get the end slice extra) and you can probably beat the speed with cython, but its a very nice feature/trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try some of the following:

- In addition to the `@cython.boundscheck(False)` compiler directive, also try adding `@cython.wraparound(False)`
- In your `setup.py` script, try adding in some optimization flags:

  `ext_modules = [Extension("accumulate", ["accumulate.pyx"], extra_compile_args=["-O3",])]`
- Take a look at the .html file generated by `cython -a accumulate.pyx` to see if there are sections that are missing static typing or relying heavily on Python C-API calls:

  http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/cythonize.html#determining-where-to-add-types
- Add a `return` statement at the end of the method. Currently it is doing a bunch of unnecessary error checking in your tight loop at `i_el += 1`.
- Not sure if it will make a difference but I tend to make loop counters `cdef unsigned int` rather than just `int`

You also might compare your code to numpy when `section_lengths` are unequal, since it will probably require a bit more than just a simple `sum`.

Comment: thanks! I implemented all your suggestions, but still there is no significant improvement. Thanks for suggesting cython -a, didn't know about that.
I added a return statement, which shows some strange checks the code is doing, see https://gist.github.com/2784725#gistcomment-330807

Comment: I am accepting this answer because it gives useful suggestions, but none of them give significant improvement. I'll change the accepted answer in case anybody else founds anything better.

Answer (score 1):

In the nest for loop update `out[i_bas]` is slow, you can create a temporary variable to do the accumerate, and update `out[i_bas]` when nest for loop finished. The following code will be as fast as numpy version:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_int_t
ctypedef np.double_t DTYPE_double_t

cimport cython
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def accumulate(
       np.ndarray[DTYPE_double_t, ndim=1] a not None,
       np.ndarray[DTYPE_int_t, ndim=1] section_lengths not None,
       np.ndarray[DTYPE_double_t, ndim=1] out not None,
       ):
    cdef int i_el, i_bas, sec_length, lenout
    cdef double tmp
    lenout = out.shape[0]
    i_el = 0
    for i_bas in range(lenout):
        tmp = 0
        for sec_length in range(section_lengths[i_bas]):
            tmp += a[i_el]
            i_el+=1
        out[i_bas] = tmp
```

Comment: thanks! followed your suggestion but there is no significant improvement, I updated my version on github